# Connection refused #111 stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://ssl0.ovh.net:465 in SwiftMailer

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, smtp, swiftmailer

I try to send email with smtp connection to my smtp client. 
I try with PHPMailer with ssl connection and it works!!
But not with SwiftMailer in Symfony 4.2...

It's for Symfony 4.2 running PHP 7.2.14.

this is my log when i try to send an email with swiftmailer...

I try everything

```
[2019-04-11 20:09:49] php.DEBUG: Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://ssl0.ovh.net:465 (Connection refused) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\SilencedErrorContext: {\"severity\":2,\"file\":\"/home/mielleriem/www/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php\",\"line\":267,\"trace\":[{\"file\":\"/home/mielleriem/www/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php\",\"line\":58,\"function\":\"establishSocketConnection\",\"class\":\"Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer\",\"type\":\"->\"}],\"count\":1})"} []
[2019-04-11 20:09:49] app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host ssl0.ovh.net [Connection refused #111] [] []
```

this is my swiftmailer.yaml

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: smtp
    host: ssl0.ovh.net
    port: 465
    auth_mode: login
    encryption: ssl
    #auth_mode: login
    username: admin@*****-a****he.fr
    password: ********
    #intercept_redirects: true
    # disable_delivery: false
    # url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

and in my .env i put this line

```
MAILER_URL=null://localhost
```

this is my first .htaccess

```
#SetEnv SHORT_OPEN_TAGS 0
#SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
#SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
#SetEnv SESSION_AUTOSTART 0
#SetEnv ZEND_OPTIMIZER 1
#SetEnv PHP_VER 7_2

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

and my second

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The port 465 is most likely blocked in your environment. Can you try with 587? Also, are you trying this locally or from a server (shared?) inside the OVH infrastructure?

Comment: @BrunoLeveque I try also with 587 and i doesnt work. I try this from the shared server. But it work perfectly with PHPMailer but for my project i need SwiftMailer

Comment: Try to add this at the beginning of your script:  ini_set('SMTP','ssl0.ovh.net');
 ini_set('smtp_port',587);

Comment: @BrunoLeveque Nothing append, always the same error, stream_socket_client()....

Comment: @BrunoLeveque I edit my question to put .htaccess file

Comment: I read on Github that there was a similar issue with Symfony/Swift, apparently it was not happening in previous versions.

Comment: Can you try to double-quote all swiftmailer parameters, empty your cache and try again ? A non quoted username could be the culprit (as it is interpreted differently)